# How do you programmatically access resolved implementation dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I would like to access the metadata about a resolved implementation dependency that has its version set via a platform bom

```
  dependencies {
      implementation platform("internal.spinnaker:clouddriver-bom:${spinnakerRelease}")
      annotationProcessor platform("internal.spinnaker:clouddriver-bom:${spinnakerRelease}")
      testAnnotationProcessor platform("internal.spinnaker:clouddriver-bom:${spinnakerRelease}")

      implementation "com.netflix.spinnaker.clouddriver:clouddriver-web"
      implementation "com.netflix.spinnaker.clouddriver:clouddriver-core"
      implementation "com.netflix.spinnaker.clouddriver:clouddriver-security"
  }
```

I would like to be able to programmatically access the resolved version of clouddriver-web.
All the solutions I can find online keep referencing code like this.

```
configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies
```

Which you cannot do with the implementation configuration as it throws an error about not being resolvable.

The end goal is to have the resolved dependency be an entry in META-INF/build-info.properties so that it can be used like so: https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-version/

I can’t figure out how to get the version in a task or gradle file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gradle 6.0, the following `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
}

task log {
  doLast {
    println(configurations.compileClasspath.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies)
  }
}
```

When run with:

```
./gradlew :log
```

Prints:

```
> Task :log
[com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre;compile]
```

Any dependency in the `implementation` configuration will show up on the compile classpath, as shown by the following figure that I've taken from [The Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html).

[image: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/img/java-main-configurations.png]

Comment: I was able to get this to work more or less. 

I had to do some shenanigans to get it to work in a plugin during the apply phase.

https://gist.github.com/fieldju/0cf16f4351ffb16b18c47e3a8b2a5b1b